# Batch changing and replacing file extension in subdirs

Tags: bash, shell, replace, file-extension, mv

I want to batch-change files which lie in subdirs. The extension of the existing files is *.ada.npp. I would like to change it to *.ada. The thing is there are files already existing with the desired extension *.ada. Those files need to be replaced.

I tried with mmv and mv extensively but was not successfull (see below).

```
mmv -rd ';*.npp' '\#1'
```

```
$ mmv -rd ';*.npp' '\#1'
mechanisation/nav_kernel/acdc_alignment.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/acdc_types.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_ke
rnel/acdc_types.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/ahrs_manager.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/ahrs_manager.2.ad
a.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/aim_augmentation.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/aim_augmentation.2.ada.npp , mech
anisation/nav_kernel/aim_types.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/aim_types.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/analy
tic_platform.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/analytic_platform.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/earth_model.1.a
da.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/earth_model.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/ecef_conversions.1.ada.npp , mechanis
ation/nav_kernel/ecef_conversions.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/egm_2008_gravity_model.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/
nav_kernel/egm_2008_gravity_model.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/fast_strapdown_manager.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/
nav_kernel/fast_strapdown_manager.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/geoid.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/geoid.
2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/gps_toolbox.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/gps_toolbox.2.ada.npp , mechanisat
ion/nav_kernel/gravity_augmentation.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/gravity_augmentation.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/
nav_kernel/gyrocompass.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/gyrocompass.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/heading_irs
_slew.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/heading_irs_slew.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/inertial_data_processin
g.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/inertial_data_processing.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/inertial_measuremen
t_pipe.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/inertial_measurement_pipe.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/input_validat
ion.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/input_validation.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/integrity_monitor.1.ada.n
pp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/integrity_monitor.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/irs_manager.1.ada.npp , mechanisati
on/nav_kernel/irs_manager.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/magvar.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/magvar.2.ada.
npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/main_manager.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/main_manager.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/
nav_kernel/main_manager_fast.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/main_manager_fast.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel
/main_manager_slow.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/main_manager_slow.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/motion_se
nsor.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/motion_sensor.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/navigation.1.ada.npp , mech
anisation/nav_kernel/navigation.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/output_preparation.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_ke
rnel/output_preparation.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/output_preparation_fast.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kerne
l/output_preparation_fast.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/pressure_altitude_augmentation.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/
nav_kernel/pressure_altitude_augmentation.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/satellites_bookkeeper.1.ada.npp , mechani
sation/nav_kernel/satellites_bookkeeper.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/sea_alignment.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav
_kernel/sea_alignment.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/stationary_heading_stabilization.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/na
v_kernel/stationary_heading_stabilization.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/strapdown_ecef.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/
nav_kernel/strapdown_ecef.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/true_airspeed_augmentation.1.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_
kernel/true_airspeed_augmentation.2.ada.npp , mechanisation/nav_kernel/zero_velocity_augmentation.1.ada.npp , mechanisat
ion/nav_kernel/zero_velocity_augmentation.2.ada.npp -> mechanisation/nav_kernel/#1 : collision.
```

Nothing done.

Comment: You want to rename files? What is a "batch-change"?

Comment: batch-change means doing the change for a large amount of files in an automated way

Comment: Maybe you just want `-o` option? See [documentation](https://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find`.

```
find . -name '*.ada.npp' -exec sh -c '
for f; do
  mv -- "$f" "${f%.npp}"
done' _ {} +
```

Comment: What does the "--" do? What does the "_ {} +" do ? Is it the same as "\;" in order to finish the command?

Comment: I am not sure if this is such a good solution (although it works). The `-exec` command is executing for every found file, why would you use a loop after that? Seems a bit odd.

Comment: Okay I take it back - [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) makes it clear that there is a differnce between `-exec command ;` and `-exec command {} +`.

Answer (score 0):

This loop will do what you need. Launch it from the top level directory where you want to start your search

```
IFS="
";for F in `find . -name "*.ada.npp"`;do B1=`echo "$F" | sed 's/.ada.npp$//'`;mv -- "$F" "$B1.ada";done
```

Comment: It would fail! Anyway, if you name a file with newlines in the name, you deserve it :)